# Why does tmux erase terminal contents on editor exit?

Tags: macos, bash, vim, emacs, tmux

Say I'm running tmux and use "ls" to get something on the screen. Then I enter Vim to edit some file. After exiting Vim, tmux erases whatever text is above the bash prompt (not like the clear command since the prompt stays in the same place).

Is there a way to prevent this behavior? I'm using tmux 1.3 in Terminal.app on OS X.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your version of `tmux` has this option, add this line to your `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set-window-option -g alternate-screen on
```

Comment: After reading the man page I think that seems related to what's going on, but I tried that setting and it didn't change anything.

Comment: @soolwan: What is your `$TERM`? Is it different with versus without `tmux`? Does `tput smcup; sleep 2; tput rmcup` switch screens and back outside `tmux`? What about within `tmux`? If that works in `tmux` (with the alt-screen setting in my answer), then you need to configure `vim` differently. In `vim`, do `set t_ti?` (and again for t_te) and compare the output to `tput smcup|hexdump -C` (and rmcup). They should be similar.

Comment: $TERM is xterm-color both inside and outside tmux. "tput smcup; sleep 2; tput rmcup" switches screens outside tmux as expected; within tmux it switches screens and when it returns everything above the prompt is erased. This is the same behavior the editors have.

Comment: Dennis, after reading your reply, I looked into $TERM. In my .bashrc I had a line "export TERM=xterm-color". Upon removing this line, tmux is working as expected. Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your .vimrc file:

```
set t_ti= t_te=
```

Comment: That makes vim not clear on exit. I want vim to clear on exit, but I want tmux to not erase the screen activity that was there before the vim session.